# How to add another miner to existing private ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have created one private ethereum blockchain with

```
geth --datadir /home/demoUser/blockchain/chainData/miner1 init /home/demoUser/blockchain/chainData/genesis.json
```

and started mining with

```
geth --identity "miner1" --networkid 42 --datadir "/home/demoUser/blockchain/chainData/miner1" --nodiscover --mine --rpc --rpcport "8042" --port "30303" --unlock 0
```

now I need to add one more miner to the same blockchain how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have direct answer but I think you should setup separate node with the same genesis config and add it as peer. Take a look at the answer posted here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6842/31247

I would recommend reviewing questions & answers at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/ because this community is dedicated to Ethereum blockchain.